# Accessing Properties of returned enumerable child records from getJSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I need some help with figuring out how to bind JSON result to a view in MVC4.

I have the following view model which returns seemingly correct JSON;

View model is

```
function task(name, duedate, overdue, phase, project, description, groups) {

var self = this;

self.name = ko.observable(name);
self.duedate = ko.observable(duedate);
self.overdue = ko.observable(overdue);
self.phase = ko.observable(phase);
self.project = ko.observable(project);
self.description = ko.observable(description);
self.group = ko.observable(groups);
}


function bTask() {
var self = this;
var parts = document.location.href.split("/");
var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
self.atasks = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON("/api/tasks/GetProjectTasks?id="+id+"&stat=Active", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        self.atasks.push(new task(val.Name, moment(val.DueDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),  val.overdue, val.Phase, val.Project, val.Description, val.Goups));

    });
 });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
var aTask = new bTask();


ko.applyBindings(aTask, document.getElementById('activetasks'));

function onLoop() {
    var self = aTask;
    var parts = document.location.href.split("/");
    var id = parts[parts.length - 1];

    $.getJSON("/api/tasks/GetProjectTasks?id=" + id + "&stat=Active", function (data) {
        self.atasks.removeAll();
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
           self.atasks.push(new task(val.Name,  moment(val.DueDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY'), val.overdue, val.Phase, val.Project,  val.Description, val.Goups));
         });

     });



  }

 setInterval(onLoop, 10000);
});
```

The JSON returned from the api is as follows;

```
[{"$id":"1","DueDate":"2013-06-05T00:00:00","Id":4,"Name":"Address UAT    Issues","Description":"Task 4 Description","Status":"Active","Phase":"Requirements   Review","Project":"RAP C1","StartDate":"2013-05-31T17:28:55.46","overdue":"error","Groups":  [{"$id":"2","Name":"Group 1","Description":"Group 1   Description","ClientId":1,"GroupType":null,"Id":1},{"$id":"3","Name":"Group   2","Description":"Group 2 Description","ClientId":1,"GroupType":null,"Id":2}]}]
```

So as you can see, it is returning 1 task with two groups, which is correct.

Looping through tasks in my view allows me to access any of the properties of a task, but I am not sure how to access the returned groups and properties.

How do I need to bind to this in the view?

Is it a case that I can foreach within the tasks foreach?

any help explaining this one greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding.

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWAQk/1/) based on your data.

```
<div data-bind="foreach : Groups">
    <span data-bind="text : $id"></span>
    <span data-bind="text : Name"></span>
    <span data-bind="text : Description"></span>
    <span data-bind="text : GroupType"></span>    
    <span data-bind="text : Id"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Damien   thanks for this  I now get a  Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Groups is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: Groups   I think its due to the way that i define "task" and do my bindings?

Comment: What do you mean by now ? You right I noticed there were some differences between the json data and your viewModel.
Groups become group. Just pay attention on typo :) .

Comment: Ah - That typo all along. I had tried the foreach before, but I guess that little 's' on the end makes all the difference. Good spot - thanks Damien